# Web API - Web Forms Project Security Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am having a problem with a project with Web API.

Inside of the global.asax file I have this and it is giving an error that says

An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HostedHttpRoute.get_RouteTemplate()'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

On this line

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="DefaultApi", routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", defaults:=New With { _
  Key .id = RouteParameter.[Optional] _
```

})

I upgraded some packages. This used to be my packages.config file

```
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

They are now upgraded to this:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Any idea why I just started getting this error after upgrading?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I have project A that references project B.
In project B there are controllers and there I am calling RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute for these controllers.

I have found in my case that problem was that in project A WebApi NuGet package version was higher than in referenced project B.